# Handling One:Many Relations on Pig Join

Tags: join, apache-pig

I have two relations in Pig that look like this:

```
rel_A: {key: chararray, some_string: chararray, some_metric: long}
rel_B: {key: chararray, some_metric2: long}
```

So for example rel_A could look like

```
{('A', 'aaa', 1)
 ('A', 'aab', 2)
 ('B', 'aaa', 3)
 ('B', 'bbb', 1)
 ('C', 'whatever', 5)}
```

And rel_B could look like

```
{('A', 100)
 ('B', 250)
 ('C', 0)}
```

I'd like to join them so that I get:

```
{('A', 'aaa', 1, 100)
 ('A', 'aab', 2, 100)
 ('B', 'aaa', 3, 250)
 ('B', 'bbb', 1, 250)
 ('C', 'whatever', 5, 0)}
```

This seems conceptually simple to me, it seems like it's just a left outer join, but I run into a problem when I try the following:

```
joined_thing = JOIN rel_A BY key LEFT OUTER, rel_B BY key;

--The error appears here
agged_flat = FOREACH joined_thing GENERATE rel_A::key as key, 
    rel_A::some_string as some_string, 
    rel_A::some_metric as some_metric, 
    rel_B::some_metric2 as some_metric2;
```

This throws:

```
Error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0:    Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (A,aaa,1), 2nd : (A,aab,2)
```

I'm sure I'm missing some conceptual basic here, but I've been pretty stumped trying to make this work, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Nich can you share your full  pig script

Comment: @sandeeprawat, the portion before this is merely loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The above will work. The specific error comes from

```
{('A', 'aaa', 1),
('A', 'aab', 2),
('B', 'aaa', 3),
('B', 'bbb', 1),
('C', 'whatever', 5)}
```

actually appearing as nested tuples like so:

```
{(('A', 'aaa', 1)
('A', 'aab', 2)),
('B', 'aaa', 3),
('B', 'bbb', 1),
('C', 'whatever', 5)}
```

Even though the script mentioned just had loads previously, one of them used a custom library which actually had a bug I failed to detect. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected , may be load is getting wrong

```
rel_A = LOAD '/user/data/A_rel.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (key: chararray, some_string: chararray, some_metric: long);
rel_B = LOAD '/user/data/B_rel.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as  (key: chararray, some_metric2: long);

joined_thing = JOIN rel_A BY key LEFT OUTER, rel_B BY key;


(A,aab,2,A,100)
(A,aaa,1,A,100)
(B,bbb,1,B,250)
(B,aaa,3,B,250)
(C,whatever,5,C,0)
```